# Quandl API CSV File Returning only the column headers

Tags: php, csv, quandl

I am trying to do a simple pull from the Quandl Data API for stock price information. I have found the following URL from their documentation that should pull the stock data for AAPL stock - https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/WIKI/AAPL.csv?trim_start=2013-12-25&trim_end=2013-12-31

If I load this URL in the browser I get the csv file just fine. However, if I try to pull the file using php, I only get the column headers of the file. Here is my code:

```
$url = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/WIKI/AAPL.csv?trim_start=2013-12-25&trim_end=2013-       12-31";
$fp = fopen($url,'r') or die("can't open file");
$csv_array = (fgetcsv($fp));
print_r ($csv_array);
```

And this returns - Array ( [0] => Date [1] => Open [2] => High [3] => Low [4] => Close [5] => Volume [6] => Ex-Dividend [7] => Split Ratio [8] => Adj. Open [9] => Adj. High [10] => Adj. Low [11] => Adj. Close [12] => Adj. Volume )

But those are just the column headers from the csv file. It doesn't contain any of the actual data.

Anyone know what might be going on here?

Thank you,
Dylan

Comment: If you plan on working with Quandl a lot, you may find my [simple PHP library](https://github.com/DannyBen/php-quandl) helpful. Here, you can just do `$data = $quandl->getCsv("WIKI/AAPL")`

Answer (score 0):

you need to loop, test the next code:

```
$fp = fopen($url,'r') or die("can't open file");
  while (!feof($fp)){
      $csv_array = fgetcsv($fp,4096,",");
      print_r($csv_array);
  }
fclose($fp);
```